# IE11 crashes, how do I gracefully find if it has hung or not?

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer-11, watir-webdriver

I wrote a program with watir webdriver that does some stuff but randomly IE will hang(I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with watir and everything to do with IE). Is there any way in ruby I can detect if the browser has crashed? It would really help me to gracefully recover. Is there some sort of event I can register to detect if it has hung and handle it automatically? Or do I have to keep checking in to see if it crashed, and kill and restart if it does? http://innov8tiv.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/fix-internet-explorer-stopped-working-and-crashing-error-1.png

Answer (score 1):

You can call `browser.exists?` and it will tell you whether the window has closed.

Every element interaction also makes this call, so depending on what you are doing when it crashes you might get a different error.

Comment: Will this work when the application is hanging with the "iexplore.exe has stopped working" dialog? http://innov8tiv.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/fix-internet-explorer-stopped-working-and-crashing-error-1.png

Comment: Yeah it will time out for sure, the issue is more that IE hangs and I need a way to detect if it has so I can kill it, and bring it back up. Essentially if it gets that "iexplore isn't responding" message I consider it hung.

Comment: If you eventually get a Net::ReadTimeout error, then Watir has to wait the 360 seconds or so until that error is thrown before it can accept any more commands. You can decrease the time of the timeout, and you can rescue that error, but both are going to be difficult. Figuring out why you are getting that message in the first place and fixing it is going to be much better solution.

Comment: It's more that IE is unstable. I honestly don't think it's a problem with watir, I think it's an issue with IE. I'd much rather constantly check the browser to see if it has hung. The problem is the ReadTimeout can happen for a lot of different reason, not just the browser hanging. I can't reliably say "I got a ReadTimeout so the browser must of hung". There are lots of reason why the ReadTimeout can occur (an issue with the webpage I'm working with is that the DOM is HUGE, I'm talking millions of chars because of how this stupid website is built. Searching for elements can cause it sometimes)

Comment: I'd suggest joining us on the freenode #selenium irc channel and asking if jimevans knows why you might be having the issue with IE. He's the IE guru. Also, how are you searching for elements? I don't think DOM size should make a huge difference in most wire calls.

Comment: You'd be surprised. IE's own developer tool hates this site. It takes 5 minutes from clicking an element to it showing up in the DOM inspection. It is truly my own personal hell.